# Постоянное соединение с сервером.

Tags: php, ajax, разработка-игр

Суть - есть он-лайн пошаговая игрушка. Каждый игрок делает ход, после того, как закончил предыдущий игрок(нажимает "завершить ход" и обновляется запись в БД). 
Вопрос - как лучше отслеживать окончание хода? Раз в полсекунды слать запрос на сервер, или как-то сделать ,чтобы сервер сам оповещал клиента?
В AJAXe я разбираюсь, но как сделать второй вариант, увы, не знаю. И нужен ли он?

Comment: Если слать в пол секунды, то тут нужен NodeJS

Comment: Ну сейчас появилось модное слово websocket...

Comment: Пинать сервер 2 раза в секунду реализуется проще всего, при этом это самое не оптимальное по ресурсам решение. Однако, это не критично, если игроков всего с десяток.
А если игроков достаточное количество, чтобы таким образом уронить сервер - юзайте(изучайте) сокеты и примеры реализации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам [пару](http://habrahabr.ru/post/116571/) [ссылок](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code) на эту тему. Если нужно больше - гуглите [long polling](https://www.google.by/search?q=long+polling+php).

Answer (score 2):

Если на html5 То websocets создает постоянное соединение с сервером, Вы только слушаете на js событие получение сообщения с сервера или наоборот отправляете что-то на сервер, очень удобная фича для таких целей. Вот например [ссылка на Хабру](http://habrahabr.ru/post/79038/)

Comment: Мысль неплохая, но есть одно НО. В IE поддержка WebSocket-ов реализована только начиная с 10 версии. Впрочем, можно найти костыли, позволяющие эмулировать их поддержку и в более ранних версиях (ищите либу web-socket-js).

Comment: я думаю тоже если есть возможность использовать технологии то стоит ими пользоваться, а иначе для чего они нужны (:стоит задача на ie6 сделать тогда понятное дело забываем все что придумали за последние n лет вешаем таймаут запросы на сервер, то есть старым, "добрым" способом...

Comment: На самом деле с вебсокетами не так всё легко. Конечно можно воспользоваться и socket.io, но это жуть какая толстенная либа. Но я бы посоветовал заюзать именно их, тем более для браузеров, которые не поддерживают такую штуку, можно сделать прослойку с помощью флеша. На худой конец long-pull, но о быстродействии можно забыть :) Хотя для пошаговой игры вполне годно.

Comment: @ilyas, в данном случае стоит позаботиться о пользователях 8 и 9 IE, доля которых пока достаточна высока (в отличие от доли пользователей IE 10). Можно, конечно, при запуске приложения под неподдерживаемыми браузерами посылать пользоваетля в пешее эротическое, но, по-моему, это неуважение к пользователю.

Comment: говоря Ie6 я имел ввиду и их по сути надо просто проверить, поддерживает делаем по новому, нет через Ж. Тут смотря какая задача стоит.

Answer (score 1):

Пишите на Node.JS + Socket.IO

Работать будет на всех браузерах. В зависимости от того, какой тип соединения поддерживает браузер, он выбирает подходящий (WebSockets, Long Polling, Flash, etc)

Работает на ура и без тормозов